# Error después de conexión a servidor vb.net mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Tengo este error al momento de intentar ejecutar la consulta:

> 'Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.

```
   Private Sub Verfactura_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    conectar()
    filtrarfecha()
    desconectar()
   End Sub

   Sub Filtarfecha()

    Dim conexion As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
    Dim comando As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand

    comando.CommandText = "SELECT p_fecha as Fecha, p_hora AS Hora, p_nfac as Factura, estatus AS Estatus,                              
                           SUM(p_monto) AS Total FROM tbl_Ventas 
                           WHERE p_fecha = '" & fechac & "'
                           GROUP by p_fecha, p_nfac"
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
    Dim daa As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(comando)
    daa.Fill(dt)
    DataGridViewX1.DataSource = dt
end sub
```

La conexión esta en un modulo:

```
Public cnn As New MySqlConnection
Public cmd As New MySqlCommand
Public ada As MySqlDataAdapter

Public Sub conectar()
    Try
        cnn.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=Venlite;Uid=root;Pwd=1234;"
        cnn.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Hola, pero a tu command en que momento le dices que conexion usar?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Buenas.
Estás abriendo una conexión en el módulo que no usas, y para el acceso usas una conexión que no has definido.
Podrías modificar tu módulo para que devuelva la conexión:

```
    Public Function conectar() as MySqlConnection
        Try
            if cnn.State = ConnectionState.Closed then
                 cnn.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=Venlite;Uid=root;Pwd=1234;"
                 cnn.Open()
            end if
            return cnn
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        Return Nothing
    End Function
```

Desde el Load() llamar sólo a FiltrarFecha():

```
      Private Sub Verfactura_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
          filtrarfecha()
      End Sub
```

Y gestionar la conexión desde FiltrarFecha directamente, cuando vayas a acceder a los datos la abres, sin olvidarte de indicar qué conexión quieres usar al sqlcommand, y de cerrarla al terminar:

```
    Sub FiltarFecha()
        Dim conexion As MySqlConnection = conecta()
        Dim comando As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand
        comando.connection = conexion
        ...
        (aquí el código que lee y trabaja con los datos)
        ...
        conexion.close()
    End sub
```

**Edito** para aclarar algunas cosas.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu ayuda, te comento que sigue el error, la idea es que cuando entre al formulario VerFactura muestre en la datagrid las ventas de la fecha actual que viene de un datetimepicker, y luego puede pedir otra, asi consecutivamente, de ahi la logica de (Conectar-VerFacturas-Desconectar) Saludos

Comment: Sí, pero el Conectar-Desconectar lo puedes hacer dentro de VerFacturas directamente y desde el Load llamas sólo a VerFacturas.

¿Dónde te da el error exactamente?

Comment: Cuando entra por primera vez funciona, cuando sucede el evento cambio de fecha, arroja un error: Not allowed change the "connectionString property while the connection (status open)...La conexión esta ON ...habria que cerrarla en el evento cambio de fecha, pero esto se puede optimizar, que abra, llame a ver facturas, si hay evento cambio de fecha, filtre y cambie la datagrid, y cerrar conexion...Eso es lo q estoy buscando...Gracias por tu interes en ayudarme...

Comment: Al final de VerFacturas() tienes que cerrar la conexión, si no te da un error al intentar abrirla de nuevo. Será suficiente con **conexion.Close()** cuando hayas terminado con la base de datos.

Comment: Hola, ya no arroja el error, pero no me esta actualizando la datagrid con el  evento cambio de fecha cuando se cambia en el DateTimePicker...gracias por la paciencia...

Comment: Si la primera vez sí te muestra datos y luego ya no, ese problema ya no tiene nada que ver con este. Así sin ver código ni nada yo revisaría que las llamadas sean correctas, y el formato de la fecha que obtienes del DateTimePicker. Si no, pues creo que por claridad lo recomendable es que hagas una nueva pregunta.

Comment: Exacto, estoy clara que ya es otra cosa, estoy revisando la carga del origen de datos del datagrid, creí que con llamar de nuevo al procedimiento refrescaba, pero no lo hace...Si no le consigo solución la hago en otra pregunta...Gracias por la ayuda...

Comment: Corriendo perfectamente, declare como función el procedimiento "Filtrar_Fecha()",  le envío como parámetro la fecha y FUNCIONA, gracias de verdad a todos...Salu2